# Get calendar to snap to one screen, rather than overlaying in the middle

Tags: multiple-monitors, calendar, clock, lubuntu

I have a problem with Lubuntu desktop in that, the calendar on the tray bar when clicking on the current time opens in the centre of the entire desktop *spanning the gap between my dual monitors* which is really annoying. I can stopgap this by adding a spacer after the current time by a certain amount to offset it - but this leaves a ridiculous gap in the tray bar. [image: desktop with calendar dead-center]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've solved this by right-clicking the tray bar and going to *panel settings* and in there making the width 100% instead of a set width of the first monitor's resolution. This has the downside of extending the tray bar across both desktops instead of one, and as such is only really a stop-gap solution.

[image: calendar-solution]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of stretching the panel across both monitors I moved the clock to the left of the panel. I right click the panel, go to "Add/Remove panel items," select digital clock and move it all the way up until it's second only to the menu.